# Java application using default font: it shouldn't be

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I have a Java application made up of several JTextPane instances encapsulated in a class I call ttPane, all arranged using a combination of BoxLayout and OverlayLayout. All of the panes are created in a single class, I call 'Screens'.

In the Screens class I create a font by reading a .ttf file and then deriving the final 'default'. As the panes are created(via ttPane), each instance calls setFont('defaultFont') for the JTextPane in the constructor.

My code is being developed on a Linux system, no IDE involved, just text edit/compile/test.

On my system, the application will occasionally go into execution and use the default Java font ('dialog') instead of the font created in the Screens class. The next execution may properly use the created font. Or not.

I expect the application to always use the specified font. I have run the application many(!) times, each execution may use the correct font or the 'dialog' font, unpredictably.

Any ideas about what might be going on? I have screen dumps of one of the applications outputs which illustrate the problem.

Comment: Random issues usually are as a result of the GUI NOT be created on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Post an [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no "minimal reproducible example" other than the 10k application itself. I have tried repeatedly to make a "minimal reproducible example" and cannot get it to fail. Hence the question posed as it was. OTOH, yo did provide an avenue for examination "result of the GUI NOT be created on the Event Dispatch Thread" Thanks.